# EditorJs Get Data from Block

Tags: javascript, editorjs

Is there a way to get the data from an editorjs block?

I can get the Block itself via e.g. `editor.blocks.getBlocksByIndex(0)` but I can't find any property that lets me get the `type` or `data` like the heading tools `level`.